# Entity Framework - the ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I have the following code:

```
using (AtlasEntities dbContext = new AtlasEntities())
{
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("today", today));

    var results = dbContext
        .MultipleResults($"EXEC [dbo].[GetPolicyPremiums] @today, parameters)
        .AddResult<PremiumDueReminderEntity>()
        .AddResult<PremiumDueReminderEntity>()
        .AddResult<PremiumDueReminderEntity>()
        .AddResult<PremiumDueReminderEntity>()
        .Execute();
/**/
    Mail mail = new Mail()
                    {
                        IsMailSent = false,
                        ErrorFailureCount = 0,
                        Body = "Body",
                        Subject = "Premium Due Reminder"
                    };
    dbContext.Mails.Add(mail);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

`AtlasEntities` is from a different project named `EntityModel` that acts as my data layer using Entity Framework with an EDMX.

The `.Execute()` works perfectly fine and I'm able to obtain the required `results` from the database.

However when I run the `dbContext.SaveChanges()` code, I get the following stack trace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at NotificationApp.PremiumNotificationManager.StartCheck() in C:\Projects\LIVE\NotificationApp\Manager\PremiumNotificationManager.cs:line 71
```

The message is:

> The underlying provider failed on Open

The inner exception is:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

I am not using `SqlConnection` anywhere in this project.

Both projects are using a similar connection string in their respective `App.config` files:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AtlasEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.AtlasModel.csdl|res://*/Data.AtlasModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.AtlasModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NAB-SHARMAB\SQLSERVER2019;initial catalog=Live_DB;persist security info=True;user id=AdminTest;password=PasswordTest;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
          providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

I have not found anyone else having this type of error and have no idea what's causing it. Please help.

Comment: Can you show the code between calling the stored procedure and adding a new mail? The code which is supposed to be in place of `/**/` in you sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the saving part in another method:

```
private static void SaveMail(string emailBody)
        {
            using (AtlasEntities dbContext = new AtlasEntities())
            {
                Mail mail = new Mail()
                {
                    IsMailSent = false,
                    ErrorFailureCount = 0,
                    Body = emailBody,
                    Subject = "Premium Due Reminder"
                };
                dbContext.Mails.Add(mail);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

It will still be helpful to know why when I create another `Context` I don't get this error. I'm not sure why it works now.

Answer (score -1):

Declare and initialize an empty list of mails

```
List<Mail> mails = new List<Mail>();
```

Then Change

```
dbContext.Mails.Add(mail);
```

to simply

```
mails.Add(mail);
```